# If you make a single googlemaps API request with multiple origin/dest addresses, does that count as a single request?

Tags: google-maps, google-distancematrix-api

Since there is a free quota of 2500, I am wondering if there's anything I could do to optimize the number of requests I make to the API.

If I make a single request with 1 origin address & 2 destination addresses, does that count as 2 requests in terms of the quota?

Thank you

Comment: The quota for the distance matrix is defined in "elements"; each element is a single address.

Answer (score 2):

The answer to your question is NO, In Distance Matrix API you have a usage limit of 2500 free elements per day (Standard Plan)[2].
where the:

Nº of Elements = Nº Origins x Nº Destinations [1]

and you can have:

- A maximum of 25 origins or 25 destinations per request.
- A Maximum 100 elements per request.
- A Maximum 100 elements per second*, calculated as the sum of client-side and server-side queries.[2]

[1] https://developers.google.com/maps/faq#usage_quotacalc

[2] https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/distancematrix#UsageLimits